# Concatenated strings that end with \0 in C

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp

Is there a way to have concatenated strings in C that are separated between them by the symbol \0?

For example. I'm creating a simple program that consists of a client (in Java) and a server (in C). The java client sends a message that has two "parts" in it, the **operation** (REGISTER, for example) and the **parameter** (USERNAME). Then, the server has to recognize the operation and the parameter and do some operations.

The thing is that, it is necessary for the operation and the parameter (both strings) to end with a \0 symbol, but doing this makes the server only recognize the operation (because when it receives the message from the client, it stops reading when it finds the \0 symbol).

Is there a way to receive the message from the client as **"OPERATION\0PARAMETER\0"** and recognize both the string for OPERATION and the string for PARAMETER?

PD: I'm implementing this program with TCP sockets, and in the client side I'm using printwriter for sending the message.

PD2: the message cannot exceed 256 bytes

Thanks in advance

Comment: To split a string into tokens it is common to use `strtok`

Comment: Are you really asking how to permit \0 within a C string?

Comment: You can use a string like this "abcdef\0rtyuo\0\0" (note the 2 zeros at end), then make your server stop when 2 consecutive zeros are received and drop the last zero byte.

Comment: Make sure the total string length is sent as well. Probably before the data itself. If you know the message cannot exceed 256 bytes you can fit the length in a byte.

Comment: Note that Java uses UTF-16 for string encoding by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep calling `recv` (accumulating the data in a buffer) until the data you have received includes two zero bytes. Once it does, parse the received data to extract both strings.

1. Empty the buffer.
2. Call `recv` to read (more) data into the buffer.
3. Count the number of zero bytes in the used part of the buffer. If it's less than 2, go to step 2.
4. Extract the two strings from the buffer. One starts at the beginning of the buffer. The other starts after the first zero byte.